# Question regarding the correlation of limit points and convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I've been told, that:

- $(i)$ $M$ is a closed set
- $(ii)$ For every convergent sequence $a_{n}$ in $M$, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty } a_{n} \in M$

are equivalent. I understand that $M$ being a closed set implies that every limit point is in $M$, so the limit of a sequence being a limit point, is also in $M$. $(i)\implies(ii)$ is clear to me. What I don't quite understand is why $(ii)\implies(i)$. Not every limit point is a limit, so you can't prove it analogously. So my question is: How can you prove $(ii)\implies(i)$?

Comment: What are the properties of the space? Are we talking metric spaces, or topological spaces?

Comment: By proving that the complement of $M$ is open

Comment: i.e. you can always find some open interval containing $P$ if $P$ belongs to the complement of $M$, for otherwise $P$ is a limiting point, since every open interval, no matter how small, contains points of $M$

Comment: Suppose $(ii)$. Let $x$ be a limit point of $M$. By definition, $x$ can be approached arbitrarily close by points of $M$ so you can build a sequence $(a_n)$ of elements of $M$ converging to $x$, and thus $x \in M$ by property $(ii)$, which makes $M$ a closed set

Comment: @Chrystomath Sady this is all the Information I was given. I know that for metric spaces for every limit point x in A there exists a sequence (an) in A that converges to x, which would work in a proof. For sake of completion let's say that M is a topological space.

Comment: For a general topological space, this isn't true. In fact, if you don't have first countability, not even all limit points (in the sense of every neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ satisfies $(U-p) \cap A \neq \phi$, for $p$ to be a limit point of $A$) are detected by sequences in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are talking about is being a *sequential space*. A sufficient (but not necessary) condition for a space to be sequential is for a space to be first-countable. Since the majority of spaces that we work with are first-countable (and usually second-countable too), oftentimes we assume that these two definitions are the same. Let us show that the equality of statements holds in first-countable spaces.

Let us first show that if $p$ is a limit point of $M$, then there exists a sequence $p_n \in M$ such that $p_n \to p$. Take a (possibly countable) neighbourhood basis of $p$ and we can modify it using intersections so that you have open sets $\{V_i\}_1^\infty$ such that $V_i \subset V_j$ if $i \geq j$. This is called a nested neighbourhood basis. Now, if $p \in M$, then just take the constant sequence $p_n = p$ and you are done. If not, then you can pick a $p_n \in (V_n \cap A)$ and from the way its set up, $p_n \to p$. So, in a first-countable space, every limit point of $M$ can be detected by a sequence in $M$. (ii) implies that as a result, every limit point is in $M$, so $M = \overline{M}$ so $M$ is closed.

On the other hand, if $M$ is closed, then $M$ contains all its limit points. Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ is a limit point of $A$ (do you see why?). Thus it belongs to $M$.

Last, we note that this is only a sufficient condition. There are spaces that are sequential but not first-countable. Wikipedia lists $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as one such space.

Edit: Since the tag you have is analysis, I'm assuming you're only working with metric spaces, which are automatically first-countable.